# How to find out if a file is a shortcut file or not in windows 7 and 8?

Tags: c#

I found a solution using shell objects, but could not get it compiled on windows 8.1. I am looking for a solution in c# which should work on windows 7 and higher.

Comment: Check out the answer documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310595/how-can-i-test-programmatically-if-a-path-file-is-a-shortcut

Comment: Hey thanks! But I checked that already, the solution given in that link doesn't work on windows 8. And the link provided in another answer is broken.

Comment: Will it be sufficient to just check the extension of the file?

Comment: Here is the document listed in the answer: http://ithreats.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/lnk_the_windows_shortcut_file_format.pdf

Comment: But this is not official documentation. I am afraid MS can change it anytime. Anyway, thanks for your time!